# Do I have to specify each endpoint in API Gateway when using GoFiber for my endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, go-fiber

I'm using GoFiber via lambda for my API, and I don't really see the value in having to hard-code all of the values in the yaml file if I'm going to handle the routing directly in GoFiber. Is that a common use case? I want to use API Gateway to have different API Keys and usage plans and rate-limiting. I can't find *any* documentation with any examples of API Gateway using GoFiber specifically.

I was hoping just to have a root route in API Gateway that passes everything else through GoFiber to authenticate etc. The only thing API Gateway would do is rate-limit and track usage per API Key.

I would authenticate inside GoFiber and would handle all responses there.

Does anybody have a link to any sort of documentation that would help me figure out a good design pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the common practice, since AWS official documentation does the same - [AWS Lambda Powertools for Python](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.14.1/core/event_handler/api_gateway/)
. Here is a Python example, but it is the same for Go.

Comment: To be clear - To route *everything* through a root endpoint is common, or specifying every endpoint manually? Apologies.

Comment: Could you explain what `manually` means in this context? Adding a new `lambda` function for each route? @JoelHager

Comment: Right now the api gateway intercepts everything and passes it to a single go fiber instance. The fiber instance does the routing and validation. I don't want to have to spin up new gateway routes or lambdas. I just didn't know if people generally used that approach.

Comment: Now I got it. You're good, that's absolutely fine.